# How to find max and min elements in array in C?

Tags: c, pointers, max, min, dynamic-memory-allocation

I created an array by using dynamic memory allocation.

I'm typing the size of array and then the elements. The program sums the elements, but doesn't find the max and min elements of this array.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>    
int main()
{    
    int size ,i ,a;
    double *element;
    printf("Dizinin Boyutunu Giriniz: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    int *ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    if (size == NULL) {
        printf("Hata! Hafiza verilemedi.");
       exit(0);
    }

    printf("Dizinin Elemanlarini Giriniz: ");

    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)    
        scanf(" %d", &ptr[i]); 

    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)    
        sum = sum + ptr[i];

    printf("Dizinin Elemanlarinin Toplami: = %d \n",sum);

    for(a=1;a<size;a++)  {
       if(*element<*(element+a)) 
           *element=*(element+a);
    }
    printf(" The Largest element is :  %.2f \n\n",*element);        

    free(ptr);
}
```

It shows the sum of the elements correctly but it doesn't show the max and min. I know there is nothing about min in the code but I couldn't figure it out. I'm also asking your help for this. How can I fix this?

This is the output:

```
Dizinin Boyutunu Giriniz: 3
Dizinin Elemanlarini Giriniz: 3
5
7
Dizinin Elemanlarinin Toplami: = 15

--------------------------------
Process exited after 19.5 seconds with return value 3221225477
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Where are you reserving space for `element`?

Comment: Actually I have no idea. Can you explain what do you mean?

Comment: You are using `element` uninitialized, it is not clear to me what you are trying to do, maybe if you put the `printf` text in english ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have correctly been told in comments section, you are trying to store maximum value to a pointer that has never been initialized. Whenever you declare a pointer you need to tell the compilere *where* it points: either the address of an existing variable (by means of unary operator `&` - in your case it would have been `double *element = &a_valid_double_variable;`) or a dynamically allocated address (using `malloc` function - in your case `double *element = malloc(sizeof double);`).

Anyway, since you populate your array with `scanf` I suggest you a different approach, by calculating min & max *"on the fly"*:

```
if(size > 0)
{
    int max, min;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
        scanf(" %d", &ptr[i]);

        if(i == 0)
        {
            max = min = ptr[i];
        }
        else
        {
            if(ptr[i] > max)
                max = ptr[i];

            if(ptr[i] < min)
                min = ptr[i];
        }
    }
    printf("Max: %d - Min: %d\n", max, min);
}
```

Basically you compare the new value with the current `min` and `max` (except for the first element that will be used to initialize them). At the end of the input phase minimum and maximum value will be already calculated.

Note: of course it all makes sense only if `size` is a positive integer.

---

So, getting rid of the useless variables, moving also the sum inside the loop and translating the messages in English your program becomes:

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{    
    int size;

    printf("Insert the number of integers (size of array): ");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    if(size > 0)
    {
        int *ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
        int max, min, sum = 0;

        printf("Insert %d integers: ", size);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
        {
            scanf(" %d", &ptr[i]);

            if(i == 0)
            {
                max = min = sum = ptr[i];
            }
            else
            {
                if(ptr[i] > max)
                    max = ptr[i];

                if(ptr[i] < min)
                    min = ptr[i];

                sum += ptr[i];
            }
        }
        printf("Sum: %d - Max: %d - Min: %d\n", sum, max, min);

        free(ptr);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid size!\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Insert the number of integers (size of array): 5
Insert 5 integers: 34 32 11 -5 7
Sum: 79 - Max: 34 - Min: -5
```

Comment: I did some research I write this code. So I didn't see anything about addressing where pointer points. Can you explain to me how can I do that. Because I rearranged my code with yours but nothing has changes. I think this is happening because of my code is lack of whatever you say.

Comment: @erensert a parenthesis was missing. You basically have to throw all the code after the sum calculation and substitute this to the part in which you scanf the array elements. It will work (I also added a printf in the end).

Comment: Btw: you can calculate also sum in the same loop.

Comment: @erensert probably you are using a c++ compiler. Try `double *element = (double *) malloc(sizeof (double));`, in C the casting is not required. **BUT:** (1) you don't need a double variable for your max, as you have an array of integers, (2) It doesn't need to be a pointer: you just need `int max;` (as in my example), (3) you don't need to add variables at all: just include my code to your function removing all the references to *element.

Comment: I did as you said. I added "if(size > 0)" section to after my summing but it still does not show max and min.

Comment: I literally tried everything but I'm stuck. It doesn't show anything after summing.

Comment: @Erensert apparently you tried anything except the correct solution. :) I tested my snipped and it works. Anyway: find in my last edit the complete function and let me know what was your mistake.

Comment: Thank you so much! My mistake is get lost in so many answers. I look to page o many times but finally saw your working answer. So sorry to asking too many questions and wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than form code that finds the sum, max, and min, consider a helper funciton that does just one of these functions.

```
// Returned pointer to min value
int *int_min(const char *ptr, size_t n) {
  int *min_ptr = NULL;
  if (n > 0) {
    *min_ptr = &ptr[0];  // Save address of first element
    for (size_t i = 1; i<n; i++) {
      if (*min_ptr < ptr[i]) {
        min_ptr = &ptr[i];    // Save address of ith element
      }
    }
  }
  return min_ptr;
}
```

Usage

```
int *min = int_min(ptr, size);
if (min) {
  printf(" The minimum element is :  %d\n", *min);
} else {
  printf(" The minimum element does not exist\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared an uninitialized pointer of the type `double *`.

```
double *element;
```

So its using in this loop

```
for(a=1;a<size;a++)  {
   if(*element<*(element+a)) 
       *element=*(element+a);
}
```

does not make sense and results in undefined behavior.

Remove the pointer declaration.

This if statement

```
if (size == NULL) {
    printf("Hata! Hafiza verilemedi.");
   exit(0);
}
```

also does not make a great sense.

It seems you mean

```
if ( ptr == NULL) {
    printf("Hata! Hafiza verilemedi.");
   exit(0);
}
```

If you need to find the maximum and the minimum elements of the dynamically allocated integer array using pointers then the corresponding code can look like

```
const int *min = ptr;
const int *max = ptr;

for ( const int *p = ptr + 1; p != ptr + size; ++p )
{
    if ( *p < *min ) 
    {
        min = p;
    }
    else if ( *max < *p )
    {
        max = p;
    }
}

printf(" The Smallest element is :  %d\n", *min );
printf(" The Largest  element is :  %d\n", *max );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n = 1; // by defaul let;s the size of the array will be equal to 1

    printf( "Dizinin Boyutunu Giriniz: " );
    scanf( "%zu", &n );

    int *ptr = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( ptr == NULL ) 
    {
        printf( "Hata! Hafiza verilemedi.\n" );
        exit(0);
    }

    printf( "Dizinin Elemanlarini Giriniz: " );

    for ( int *p = ptr; p != ptr + n; ++p )
    {
        *p = rand() % ( int )n;
    }

    for ( const int *p = ptr; p != ptr + n; ++p )
    {
        printf( "%d ", *p );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    const int *min = ptr;
    const int *max = ptr;

    for ( const int *p = ptr + 1; p != ptr + n; ++p )
    {
        if ( *p < *min ) 
        {
            min = p;
        }
        else if ( *max < *p )
        {
            max = p;
        }
    }

    printf( "The Smallest element is :  %d\n", *min );
    printf( "The Largest  element is :  %d\n", *max );

    free( ptr );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Dizinin Boyutunu Giriniz: 10
Dizinin Elemanlarini Giriniz: 3 6 7 5 3 5 6 2 9 1 
The Smallest element is :  1
The Largest  element is :  9
```

Comment: Your code is working but Elements of the array shouldn't be random. I need to give them myself

Comment: @Erensert What is the problem?! Use the code snippet that finds the minimum and the maximum with your arrays. It is just a demonstrative program that shows how the minimum and the maximum can be found.